# How to identify unknown component

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, identification, rfid

I've recently got myself a bus pirate to read an EEPROM which is labelled fm24c32a since that's the only thing I could recognize on the board (the IC was covered by a blob). I managed to identify a little more than half the pins on the IC (LCD, Antenna, EEPROM, CLOCK, VCC, GND) out of the 100 pins but I don't know if there is a way to find the IC back with this information only.

So as I was stuck with this I moved to another circuit which uses RFID and has a chip on board (yay...) and two other components : One unlabeled (no text on it, 8 pins, 6 pins soldered) and another (8 pins) one with this text:

```
emsfic
814100A
2G
```

This labeled module is linked to the RFID antenna but I can't find any datasheet.

So my question is how do you go about identifying an unknown component or one with label on it (I didn't manage to find anything about the emsfic component on the Internet).

And specifically what is this emsfic component above and how do you go about identifying component because I can't seem to find anything useful.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the noob question...

Edit : Turns out after unsoldering the unlabeled 8 pins chip, it is labeled on the bottom side of the chip as follow :

```
DT1502
1?081 (? could be a 1 or T)
FC05061 0E
```

Also from a [PDF](https://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-21/dc-21-presentations/Phorkus-Evilrob/DEFCON-21-Phorkus-Evilrob-Hacking-Embedded-Devices-Bad-things-to-Good-hardware.pdf) i read on the internet this is most likely an SPI Flash chip since its layed out this way :

```
    ---- VCC
    -  -
    -  -
GND ----
```

I've tried doing an I2C scan but no address was found. Under the unsoldered chip was written P15.

But once again i couldn't find anything with this info so idk what im doing wrong :/

Here is a picture of the second board :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to the antenna design, the system appears to be a LF RFiD system (125kHz or 134kHz).

- The chip you are searching the reference if a LF RFiD transceiver.
- The package is a SOIC-8.

Maybe your component is a MELEXIS MLX90109. The pinout seems to match. (antenna coil position).